# Hello, I'm trying to delete a record with the record on my mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i need help on my mobile application `<%= link_to 'Eliminar', category, :confirm => "Eliminar categoria ?", :method => :delete %>`
but the link does not work,

Comment: any errors? show your console log.

Comment: no just not working the link take me to that object show page any help pls

Comment: check your controller

Comment: it not working on my mobile but i my full site it working well

Answer (score 0):

Click on the link on your mobile and check your console it actually go to the action or not.i think i may be a css issue some other elements may be overlap on it.

```
<%= link_to "/categories/#{categoty.id}", method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' },:class=>"btn btn-danger",:title=>"Remove" do %><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i><%end%>
```

Comment: it take me to my show page, in my full site it look great and work fine

Comment: <%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>&nbspDelete '.html_safe, article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' },:style=>"color:red" %>

Comment: Try the update code.it seems your response method is not delete it's hits the show action

Comment: the update work just fine, i think is all my post method that is have this problem too, pls if you have any way so i can get it right or link to read on my mobile.erb

Answer (score 0):

```
<%  @articles.each do |article| %>
<div class="mobile-article-index">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <div class="mobile-normal">
      <ul>
        <li >
          <%=link_to article.page.name, article.page %>
        </li>
        <li >
          <%=link_to  article.title, article %>
        </li>
        <%= article.created_at.strftime("%B %e, %Y") %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-normal" style="font-size: 80%">
      <%=image_tag article.image_url.to_s, :width=>"60%;",:height=>"78px;",:style => " border-radius: 5px;"%>
      <%= raw summarize(article.body, 190) %><%=link_to "read more" ,article ,:class=>"page-button"%>
      <%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>&nbspDelete '.html_safe, article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' },:style=>"color:red" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```